# Is it possible to view the build definition of a past build run draft?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am finalizing a build pipeline where I'm trying to publish artifacts to Azure App Service. However, I'm running into a certain issue, but last week, I somehow resolved that issue but forgot to publish the draft, and I ended up adding more tasks that just messed up the working version from last week. I still have the run showing, but I don't see a way to view the task details (such as parameter or path configurations).

Is it possible to view these details? Perhaps view the YAML of that draft that worked?

[image: workingrun]

So by task details I mean like this:

[image: task details]

Clicking edit pipeline takes me to the current draft, which is the one that's not working. Is it not then possible to look at task details of past build drafts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> clicking edit pipeline takes me to the current draft, which is the one thats not working. Is it not then possible to look at task details of past build drafts?

Open current draft definition, click the tab **History**, we could check the update history.

Then we could click the button **Compare Difference** to compare the current draft version with the previous version definition info. And click the button **Revert Pipeline** to restore to the previous version

[image]

Comment: Carlos you're awesome! This is exactly what i needed! wish theers a build id field to recognize it easier. hopefully thats a feature to add in the future

Answer (score 0):

If you ever save a draft build pipeline but do not publish it, there will be a tiny "**DRAFT**" indication in pipeline view,  as below.
[image]
[image]
You could click it to view the draft build pipeline, as below.
[image]

Comment: This takes me to the current draft definition, i want to go to a previous draft build definition. @Carlos answer works though :)